# big-O notation for logarithmic functions

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I want to calculate the big-O notation for logarithmic functions such as $f(x) = \log_3(x^3) + \log_2(x^x)$
For the first part,

$\log_3(x^3) = 3\log_3(x)$ and it's ${\cal O}(log_3(x))$

but how to we calculate the big-O for the second part? is it simply ${\cal O}(log_2(x^x))$ and since ${\cal O}(log_2(x^x))$ is bigger than ${\cal O}(log_3(x))$ then $f(x)$ is ${\cal O}(log_2(x^x))$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a small nitpick: there is no point in specifying the base of the logarithm in the $O(\cdot)$, since they all just differ by a constant factor. So it's OK to simply write
$$
\log_3(x^3) = 3\log_3 x = O(\log x)\,.
$$

For the second; you can do the same at first: use the rule that $\log(a^b) = b\log a$.
$$
\log_2(x^x) = x\log_2 x = O(x\log x)
$$
and you are done.